# How to use Servlet in Struts2

Tags: servlets, struts2

How to use `servlets` together with `Struts2`?

Comment: Why don't you buy a book like 'Struts2 in Action'. Check out http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-tutorial/struts-2-tutorial.html. When you have specific problem ask a question here.

Comment: Both the question and answer seemed clear to me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I assume you want to know how to use a servlet in conjunction with Struts2 when you have mapped everything to the Struts2 filter.

You can use the following in your `struts.xml`:

```
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/YourServlet"/>
```

You can exclude multiple patterns by separating them with a comma, such as:

```
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/YourServlet,/YourOtherServlet"/>
```

**More Information**

- [Filter mapping for everthing to Struts2 besides one servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843548/filter-mapping-for-everthing-to-struts2-besides-one-servlet)
- [Filters not working in Struts2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421764/filters-not-working-in-struts2)

Comment: here is the offical link: https://struts.apache.org/docs/static-content.html 
  read: "Preventing Struts from Handling a Request" section

Answer (score 4):

There are three ways to resolve this problem:

1. add constant tag in struts.xml

   `<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/YourServlet,/YourOtherServlet"/>`
2. add suffix in servlet configuration in web.xml

   `<servlet-mapping>`

   `<servlet-name>Authcode</servlet-name>`

   `<url-pattern>/authcode.servlet</url-pattern>`

   `</servlet-mapping>`

   Because in struts 2, it will only intercept all the request end with .action, if this request do not have any suffix, it will automatically add it. When we make our servlet url-pattern have a suffix, then struts 2 will not intercept it anymore.
3. implement a user-defined filter

Comment: Not true - *Because in struts 2, it will only intercept all the request end with .action*.

Comment: which one is not true? no.2? servlet can work together with struts2, you can try it.

Comment: This part is wrong - *Because in struts 2, it will only intercept all the request end with .action.*

Comment: THANKS BOTH OF YOU

Answer (score 1):

Servlets technology is more low level architectural layer than Struts2. Even more Struts2 is embedded to your project as a filter (that is part of servlet technology).

So to add one more servlet just add to web.xml registration:

```
<servlet>

    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>class.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need multi mapping servlet you can using:

```
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/Servletname1, /Servletname2" />
```

But in struts, you should not using servlet url because it not unity. You can use ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
            url : "nameAction.action?param="+id,
                   type : "post",
            data : {
                'id' : id

            },
            success : function(data) {
    //          $('#result').html(data);
            },
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#result').html("Error");
            }
        });
```