# How to configure URL patterns to have servlet and Struts2 to work simultaneously?

Tags: java, regex, servlets, struts2, servlet-mapping

Why my filtering does not work for me and how to setup it to work?

There is my `web.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<servlet>
    <display-name>GameServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>GameServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ajaxdemo.action.GameServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GameServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/gameservlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

On this configuration `GameServlet` does not receive anything and web server reports that there are no action mapping for `/gameservlet` URL.

If I comment filter-mapping this servlet works fine by this URL.

How to get working Struts filters and servlet filter simultaneously, the point is servlet should work only with `/gameservlet` URL, all others should be processed by Struts. I cannot understand how to create URL patterns for my case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Servlet in Struts2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295491/how-to-use-servlet-in-struts2)

Comment: from first view duplication, don't know to accept it or not, the point is I knew that Servlet and Struts can work together, it is why I didn't find that you specified, my question is more precise to problem, for me question was exactly concerned to patterns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jersey with Struts2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293115/jersey-with-struts2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `excludePattern` constant to `struts.xml` to exclude servlet mapping URL from Struts processing.

```xml
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/gameservlet/?.*"/>
    ...
</struts>
```

Comment: It works, thank you very much, I have seen tons of tutorials for Struts and servlets and could not find this very simple thing.