# how to configure a servlet as a filter

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2, web.xml, servlet-filters

I am trying to simulate something like `L7` in struts. where we have a lot of filters in `web.xml`. but when the URL pattern matches something like `"abc/qwe"`the `L7` simulation filter must skip all the filters after it and execute a servlet.

Comment: what happens when I configure a servelet before a filter in web.xml, will the filter get executed before servelet?

Comment: You can't use both https://stackoverflow.com/a/29087379/573032