# struts2 + SPRING MVC + Rest Api integration . Struts not working

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, struts2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaeehttp://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" version="4.0">
    <absolute-ordering />
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:appContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
                </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springrest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
                </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:springrest-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springrest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/springrest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Rest api is working well I tried using postman. But when I run my application the struts action was not calling and whenever am using servlets tags in web.xml, the struts2 is not working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29087379/573032

Answer (score 0):

my mistake was i involved **struts-convention** and **struts-json** plugins .

i am integrating REST api with Spring . but struts will jst calls the action . because of involving those two plugins in pom.xml . the error raised.

**thankyou**