# Changing URL pattern to specific redirection in Struts 2 filter

Tags: xml, struts2, web.xml, url-pattern

Currently in our web.xml, it's going to Struts 2 filter for all the urls since it's /*, but I need to give specific URL pattern (eg: `/docupload/*`) because I am integrating with another application now.

So another application URL also goes through Struts filter and not working.

```
            <filtermapping><url-pattern>/*</url-pattern><filtermapping>
```

I tried this: I gave "namspace" in struts.xml like 'docupload':

```
  <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
  <package name="default" namespace="/docupload" extends="struts-default">
```

Added the namespace as /docupload and below is my folder structure

[image: -created docupload folder under jsp-]

in web.xml -

```
       <url-pattern>/docupload/*</url-pattern>
```

after creating folder structure and namspace added - I changed the URL pattern as above mentioned one. But it's not working.

Comment: You need to [use excludePattern as described here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5298740/1654265), but +1 for having tried something, even if wrong ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to bypass a specific URL, you can use `excludePattern` in your struts.xml as below

```xml
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/docupload/*" />
```